# Php Wso Shell and Simple Shell returns Blank Page - Why?

Tags: php, server

I just uploaded a simple shell as well as a WSO shell on a web server for running shell command. But the php file seems to open a blank page. Any Ideas why's this happening?

Comment: Did you look at your error logs? Most likely, it holds the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP realms the blank page you are encountering is also known as the WSOD (White Screen Of Death, most probably in reference to Windows' Blue Screen Of Death).

This issue happens when the PHP engine encounters an low level irrecoverable error while no output has been produced yet. The most common cause of the issue it when the PHP file contains a syntax error making parsing fail.

This syntax error is usually caused either by the webshell using a syntax not supported by the PHP version running server-side, or by an incorrect invocation of your PHP code (this is mostly true for PHP injection techniques, but your question gives me the impression you are simply uploading a raw PHP file).

Note that while this are the most common causes, there can be other causes as well, mainly related to specific settings which may have been applied on the remote server.

The solution to get around this is to limit your features to the ones you really need and implement them in a way supported by the remote server. This can be manually attempted by trying to manually create PHP one-liners such as `<?php eval($_GET['cmd']); ?>` which will attempt to execute any command you provide as `cmd` GET parameter.

BTW, if you like you can also give a try to [my own attempt](https://github.com/WhiteWinterWolf/WhiteWinterWolf-php-webshell) to write a PHP web-shell targeted at just getting the job done and done right. I wrote it out-of-frustration of several issues I encountered with other more "featureful" web-shells. Feedbacks are welcome ;).

Comment: Thanks I figured it out! Actually The Server had shell scripts disabled by default. Thanks A lot !! 

Answer (score 0):

Can we have the sourcecode ?

Most of these shell are just passing command trough a GET request, are you sure you're sending it ?

Also is this your own server, because I think you can actually prevent some PHP functions to be executed(see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions).